# JavaFx change background color of disabled textarea

Tags: javafx

I need to use textarea in my program and I also need it to be read-only.

This is part of my main program where I create textArea:

```
 final TextArea ta = new TextArea();
            ta.setMaxSize(9*x, 7*x);
            ta.setId("textarea");
            ta.setTranslateX(x);
            ta.setTranslateY(2*x);
            ta.setDisable(true);
```

This is part of my css file:

```
#textarea {
    -fx-font: 13px "Serif";
    -fx-background-color: BEIGE;
}
```

If I delete the row: ta.setDisable(true); Css works like I want it to work. But after I set disable true, it just makes the textarea transparent, which makes the text really hard to read and the background color is not excatly what I want too.

Is there any other way to set text readonly? Or is there a way to use css after disable. I really need it to be TextArea not Label or any other type. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the user to make changes to the textarea use the [setEditable(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setEditable%28boolean%29) method to false. The same method exists for most editable nodes in javafx(Textfield and PasswordField).

Comment: You mean setEditble to false. But yes it worked, thank you very much.